# Jsoup cannot read data with ID?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to read an element with ID `main_LbStatsOpenProfit` from http://www.zulutrade.com/trader/104769 but it is always empty. I have tested it on try Jsoup http://try.jsoup.org/ and it works fine.

I have read many other values with ID and those ones worked fine.

Any Ideas why this isolated problem might occur?
or any other parser example that can read this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `html()` on the selected `Element`? If so it won't work as the `Element` in the html of the given url is empty.

Try the below code :

```
doc.select("#main_LbStatsOpenProfit").first().toString()
```

Comment: This does not work Either. It gets the span but it is empty for some reason. It is not in actual page

Comment: It is indeed. The text you see in the `span` tag is inserted by `Javascript` after document load. Hence, `Jsoup` always see an empty tag.